# Persistent error: pydot and graphviz ('Failed to import pydot)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
   from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

I am working from Spyder and on windows 10. I have tried almost any solutions available on the stackoverflow and internet, and still having the same problem. When I install pydot, graphviz, pydot-ng, either through conda, or pip or pip3, and manually installing graphviz through windows insaller and adding its path to the system, I still get the same error as below:

```
    plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)
```

('Failed to import pydot. You must `pip install pydot` and install graphviz (https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/), ', 'for `pydotprint` to work.')

On my spyder, when I say either of these, I get this error:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydot'
```

or:

```
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydotplus'
```

I also restarted the kerner but did not help!

Answer (score 0):

Run in console or install for conda environment

pip install pydot

install graphviz for windows https://graphviz.org/download/ , install as Administrator

restart conda